# How to catch URL user was trying to reach with ErrorDocument in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So I have my .htaccess file in Apache with

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?e=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?e=500
```

I want it to send along the URL the user was trying to reach, so something like

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?e=400&u=URL
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?e=401&u=URL
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?e=403&u=URL
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404&u=URL
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?e=500&u=URL
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to pass requested URI with `ErrorDocument` directive. Alternatives are;

1) Use a PHP script as error handler and grab the requested URI with PHP.

*.htaccess*:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

*404.php*:

```
if (!isset($_GET['search'])) {

        $q = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . '/404.php?search=' . $q);
        die();

} else {

        // your search code...

}

?>
```

2) Use **mod_rewrite**.

*.htaccess*:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /404.php?search=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=404]
```